# How to use video for traning deep learning (caffe & digits)?

Tags: computer-vision, deep-learning, video-processing, caffe, nvidia-digits

Based on [a](https://github.com/chuckcho/video-caffe), [b](https://github.com/facebook/C3D), [c](https://github.com/chuckcho/video-caffe/tree/master/examples/c3d_ucf101), [d](http://machinelearning2015.ru/en/courses/saenko1-2), [Action Recognition with Deep Learning](https://github.com/skylian/caffe-action), [Long-term Recurrent Convolutional Networks](http://jeffdonahue.com/lrcn/), [e](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-train-a-deep-neural-network-to-detect-moving-objects-from-a-video-sequence-specifically-far-small-objects-where-the-main-signal-for-us-as-humans-is-their-motion-non-static-camera), [Generic Features for Video Analysis](http://vlg.cs.dartmouth.edu/c3d/),... there are several methods for analyses video by caffe but what is exactly the input for caffe.
Can we put video in different folders like image for training?

Comment: Please create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for any one of these methods.

Comment: based on LSTM we can use video in Caffe. However, using several videos in different folder for the video classification like image still need improvement. Do you have any implemented version of Caffe which can use it for video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DIGITS doesn't support video data yet. When we do we'll add some sort of video example here:

https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 0):

As far as my experience, you can't directly do it with digits, because in digits no default settings for sequences of frame analysis. A very famous project in Caffe known as [C3D](https://github.com/facebook/C3D) for action recognition can be used for training a new model or fine-tune existing moded for action or activity recognition. 
[C3D](https://github.com/facebook/C3D)